# ASP.Net MVC Return to same view, using a specific layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view where I'm using a specific layout.cshtml file, other than the main shared layout page: "_LayoutExCr"

This is fine for the Get part of the controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Exhibitor/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View("Create","_LayoutExCr");
    }
```

This works fine - and displays the Create view with the specific _LayoutExCr "master" page.

However, in my POST for the Create method, if the wrong access code is entered, I want to return to the same view, using the _LayoutExCr "master" page - but VS2012 Express underlines in Red:

```
 return View(exhibitor, "_LayoutExCr");
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments

```
    //
    // POST: /Exhibitor/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Exhibitor exhibitor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (exhibitor.AccessCode == "myaccesscode")
            {
                db.Exhibitors.Add(exhibitor);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Thankyou");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Access Code provided is incorrect.");
                return View(exhibitor, "_LayoutExCr");
            }

        }

        return View(exhibitor, "_LayoutExCr");
    }
```

Can anyone let me know how to return the model to the view, using that same layout page please?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Why don't you just set the layout in the view?

Comment: Hi - no real reason - to be honest, this is the first time I've used anything other than the default layout in MVC - and didn't really know how!  Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492244(v=vs.98).aspx

You want a different overload:

`return View("Create", "_LayoutExCr", exhibitor);`

1st parameter is the name of the view.  2nd is the name of the master.  3rd is the model you want to send to the view.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the view name **and** the master name, and both of them [before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492244%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) the model